# How to pass multiple values for a single name in a HTML form through PHP and INSERT in DB

Tags: php, arrays

I m working a simple shopping cart page, where it reads the products list in the cart table where user id = user id, and get the listed products details using the product id.

however once the user clicks the "checkout" button, he's submitting the product details to a PHP where it inserts those passed values to another table.

My code goes as:

**Cart.php**

```
<form action="final.php" method="post" >
 <?php 
        $sql4 = "SELECT * FROM cart WHERE u_id = '$u_id'";
        $result4 = $conn->query($sql4);
        if ($result4->num_rows > 0) { 
        while($row4 = $result4->fetch_assoc()) { 
            $p_id = $row4["p_id"];
?>
<?php 
        $sql5 = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = '$p_id'";
        $result5 = $conn->query($sql5);
        if ($result5->num_rows > 0) { 
        while($row5 = $result5->fetch_assoc()) { 
?>
    <li class="cart-item">
       <div class="product-line-grid">
        <div class="product-line-grid-left col-md-3 col-xs-4">
          <span class="product-image media-middle">
          <img src="img/products/<?php echo $row5["pic"]; ?>" alt="Mammo diablo except obtain">
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="product-line-grid-body col-md-4 col-xs-8">
        <div class="product-line-info">
        <a class="label" href="indi.php?id=<?php echo $row5["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $row5["name"]; ?></a>
       </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="p_id" value="<?php echo $row5["id"]; ?>" />
       <div class="product-line-info">
        <span class="value" ><input class="form-control" disabled type="text" id="input1<?php echo $row5["id"]; ?>" value="<?php echo $row5["price"]; ?>"/></span>
      </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="price" value="<?php echo $row5["price"]; ?>" />
         <br>
       <div class="product-line-info">
      <span class="label"><strong>Available Stock :  </strong></span>
      <span class="value"><?php echo $row5["stock"]; ?></span>
       </div>
    <div class="product-line-info">
      <span class="label"><strong>Category :  </strong></span>
     <span class="value"><?php echo $row5["cat"]; ?></span>
  </div>
      <div class="product-line-info">
      <span class="label"><strong>Sub Category :  </strong></span>
    <span class="value"><?php echo $row5["subcat"]; ?></span>
   </div>
     <input type="hidden" name="stock" value="<?php echo $row5["stock"]; ?>" />
    </div>
     <div class="product-line-grid-right product-line-actions col-md-5 col-xs-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 hidden-md-up"></div>
      <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-6">
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
      <div class="">
        <input class="form-control qty5" id="input2<?php echo $row5["id"]; ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $row4["quantity"]; ?>" name="quantity" min="1" style="display: block; background-color:white;border:1px solid lightblue;">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-2 price">
      <span class="product-price">
     <strong><input class="form-control qty1" disabled onblur="sum();" value="<?php echo $row5["price"]; ?>" name="eachfinal" type="text" id="output<?php echo $row5["id"]; ?>"  /></strong>
       </span>
      </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 text-xs-right">
     <div class="cart-line-product-actions ">
     <a class="remove-from-cart" href="deletecart.php?id=<?php echo $row4["id"]; ?>" >
      =<i class="material-icons pull-xs-left">delete</i>
</a>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="clearfix"></div>
 </div>
 </li>

<?php 
    }
        } else {
         }
    ?>
<?php 
     }
        } else {
  }
?>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Checkout</button>
</form>
```

Final.php :

```
<?php

$p_id=$_POST["udf1"];
$price=$_POST["price"];
$stock=$_POST["stock"];

$conn = new mysqli ($servername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }

$sql = "INSERT INTO final (p_id, price, stock)
        VALUES ('$p_id', '$price', '$stock')";


        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo 'added successfully';

}
        else {
            echo "ERROR" . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }

?>
```

However, this code works fine if I have only one product in the cart and I m passing the same product value, yet, if I have multiple products in the cart and I want to pass all their values and insert their values, it fails.

Using Arrays is important here, and I m here seeking help from you to explain how it's done.

NOTE: Please ignore about SQL injection, since I m a beginner I wanna try normally and later opt for it.

Comment: Simplest thing is to turn your input names into an array `name="quantity"` can become `name="row[0][quantity]"` where [0] is the index or id of your row.

Comment: `NOTE: Please ignore about SQL injection, since I m a beginner I wanna try normally and later opt for it.`You will be doing yourself a big favor to just spend a few hours learning how to use parameterized queries.  Here is a good link for you to start with. Pretty much shows you everything you need to know to start.  https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection

Comment: If we obey your wish to tolerate insecure code, StackOverflow runs the risk of teaching bad practices to uninformed researchers.  When you ask a question here, we don't just answer to help YOU, we answer using best practices with the intent to educate thousands of future researchers.  This site is a living archive of knowledge.

Comment: When using `SELECT` to extract a single column from your database table, don't write `*` as habit/laziness; rather you should name the column.  You should also avoid iterated queries. Always endeavor to minimize total queries in your script.  It looks like you should be performing a `JOIN` on `p_id`.

Comment: `$conn->query($sql) === TRUE` is more simply written as `$conn->query($sql)` with the same meaning.

Comment: You need to check if `$_POST`ed elements exist before trying to access/use them.  If your values are expected to be integers, cast them as `(int)` to improve security.  If your database table is expecting integers, you don't need to single-quote wrap the values.  That said, my overarching advice is to use prepared statements with placeholders for security reasons.

Comment: `$result5->num_rows > 0` is more simply written as `$result5->num_rows` with the same meaning.

Comment: `id="input1<?php echo $row5["id"]; ?>"` (and others)  I wonder why you are declaring these semi-variable `id` values.   Would you rather use a class? Or a `data-` value?  Please explain you intent/usage.

Comment: @Scuzzy would you please post your advice so that the OP can receive a professional grade answer (and so that I can endorse/upvote it)?

Answer (score 1):

Using array like:

Cart.php

```
<form action="final.php" method="post" >
 <?php 
        $sql4 = "SELECT * FROM cart WHERE u_id = '$u_id'";
        $result4 = $conn->query($sql4);
        if ($result4->num_rows > 0) { 
        while($row4 = $result4->fetch_assoc()) { 
            $p_id = $row4["p_id"];
?>
<?php 
        $sql5 = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = '$p_id'";
        $result5 = $conn->query($sql5);
        if ($result5->num_rows > 0) { 
        while($row5 = $result5->fetch_assoc()) { 
?>
    <li class="cart-item">
       <div class="product-line-grid">
        <div class="product-line-grid-left col-md-3 col-xs-4">
          <span class="product-image media-middle">
          <img src="img/products/<?php echo $row5["pic"]; ?>" alt="Mammo diablo except obtain">
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="product-line-grid-body col-md-4 col-xs-8">
        <div class="product-line-info">
        <a class="label" href="indi.php?id=<?php echo $row5["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $row5["name"]; ?></a>
       </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="p_id[<?php echo $row5["id"]; ?>]" value="<?php echo $row5["id"]; ?>" />
       <div class="product-line-info">
        <span class="value" ><input class="form-control" disabled type="text" id="input1<?php echo $row5["id"]; ?>" value="<?php echo $row5["price"]; ?>"/></span>
      </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="price[<?php echo $row5["id"]; ?>]" value="<?php echo $row5["price"]; ?>" />
         <br>
       <div class="product-line-info">
      <span class="label"><strong>Available Stock :  </strong></span>
      <span class="value"><?php echo $row5["stock"]; ?></span>
       </div>
    <div class="product-line-info">
      <span class="label"><strong>Category :  </strong></span>
     <span class="value"><?php echo $row5["cat"]; ?></span>
  </div>
      <div class="product-line-info">
      <span class="label"><strong>Sub Category :  </strong></span>
    <span class="value"><?php echo $row5["subcat"]; ?></span>
   </div>
     <input type="hidden" name="stock[<?php echo $row5["id"]; ?>]" value="<?php echo $row5["stock"]; ?>" />
    </div>
     <div class="product-line-grid-right product-line-actions col-md-5 col-xs-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 hidden-md-up"></div>
      <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-6">
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
      <div class="">
        <input class="form-control qty5" id="input2<?php echo $row5["id"]; ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $row4["quantity"]; ?>" name="quantity[<?php echo $row5["id"]; ?>]" min="1" style="display: block; background-color:white;border:1px solid lightblue;">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-2 price">
      <span class="product-price">
     <strong><input class="form-control qty1" disabled onblur="sum();" value="<?php echo $row5["price"]; ?>" name="eachfinal" type="text" id="output<?php echo $row5["id"]; ?>"  /></strong>
       </span>
      </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 text-xs-right">
     <div class="cart-line-product-actions ">
     <a class="remove-from-cart" href="deletecart.php?id=<?php echo $row4["id"]; ?>" >
      =<i class="material-icons pull-xs-left">delete</i>
</a>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="clearfix"></div>
 </div>
 </li>

<?php 
    }
        } else {
         }
    ?>
<?php 
     }
        } else {
  }
?>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Checkout</button>
</form>
```

Final.php :

```
<?php

$prices=$_POST["price"];
$stocks=$_POST["stock"];

$conn = new mysqli ($servername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

foreach ($prices as $p_id => price) {
  $stock = $stocks[$p_id];
  $sql = "INSERT INTO final (p_id, price, stock)
          VALUES ('$p_id', '$price', '$stock')";


  if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo 'added successfully';
  } else {
      echo "ERROR" . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
  }
}
?>
```

The most important part is in html tag "input".

Comment: Yuck.  No.  This is insecure code that no smart developer should use.

Comment: Why pass the `p_id` array from the form if you have no intention of using it?

Comment: @mickmackusa Yes, I know the risk for this code. But I just tell the author that this is the way how to solve the problem.

Comment: This is not the only way to solve the problem.  If you know the risk, don't teach it.